# C++ Can't access public variable between classes

Tags: c++, global-variables, public, getter

I've been trying desperately to get share a public variable between two classes in C++, but I can't seem to get the hang of it. I've tried getters and setters and calling it directly as a static variable but nothing.

This is what I've tried:

**DataGrabber.h**

```
#pragma once

class DataGrabber {
    public:
        static float temp;

        void readProcess(){
            temp = 1.2;
        }
 }
```

**Particle.h**

```
#pragma once

class Particle {
     public:
           void update() {
                float x = DataGrabber::temp; 
           }
```

**AND THEN THIS:**

**DataGrabber.h**

```
#pragma once

class DataGrabber {
    public:
        float temp;

        float get(){return temp;}

        void readProcess(){
            temp = 1.2;
        }
 }
```

**Particle.h**

```
#pragma once

class Particle {
     public:
           void update() {
                float x = DataGrabber.get(); 
           }
```

They are both being #include in another main header, testApp.h.

Comment: No idea what you're asking.

Comment: `DataGrabber` is a _type_ and cannot be used like they are in your second example. If you want to call it without an instance of `DataGrabber` the member (i.e. `get`) needs to be `static` _and_ you need to provide a well qualified name like `DataGrabber::get` or `DataGrabber::temp`,

Comment: First example looks like it might work.  What error message do you get? Are you including DataGrabber.h from Particle.h?

Comment: Which DataGrabber's data do you want to grab? (By making it a class, if it's not static, you're saying there might be more than one!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the exact problem? How do you use these classes?

Regardless, there are several problems with your getter code.

First, why do you use getter if you make the variable public? If you are going for this design, you should hide the variable as private, to protect it from direct modification.

Second, if it is a simple member variable, you should access it through an object that you pass to your function:

```
void update(DataGrabber& grabber) {
    float x = grabber.get();
}
```

In this case, you would have to create this object in your main code, which you have not shown.

If you want to use a static variable instead, take a look at a Singleton pattern, but I would advise against it unless there are no better options for your exact problem.

Finally, you should #include all direct dependencies in your header files. Your Particle depends on DataGrabber, so you should include its header from Particle.h. Or, at least, you should add a forward declaration.